# Elementary os no sound after alsa update

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I am new to Linux but really love Elementary for its simplicity. After noticing that my sound was quite poor in Elementary, compared to Windows 8.1, I have tried updating the sound drivers. I ended up downloading one from [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2) but after a reboot, my sound icon was gone from the toolbar and no sound can be heard. In the setting > sound I see "Dummy Output" and running alsamixer says cannot open mixer: No such file or directory. I have Googled around without any success and many suggest `sudo alsa force-reload` but that returns

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).
```

I have lost hope after posting in other places without any replies and I am hoping somebody here can help. I have uninstalled the driver I have previously downloaded from the link above (maybe there are pieces left behind?) and purged reinstalled both alsa-base and pulseaudio but I still can not see the sound icon or play sounds.

`sudo lshw`:

```
description: Portable Computer
product: Inspiron 3537 (Inspiron 3537)
vendor: Winbond Electronics
version: A07
serial: 2FN1402
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=portable family=00 frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=Inspiron 3537 uuid=44454C4C-4600-104E-8031-B2C04F343032
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: 03JPPR
   vendor: Winbond Electronics
   physical id: 0
   version: A00
   serial: .2FN1402.CN129664280036.
   slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Winbond Electronics
      physical id: 0
      version: A07
      date: 11/12/2013
      size: 128KiB
      capacity: 4032KiB
      capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 4
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
      serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      slot: U3E1
      size: 759MHz
      capacity: 759MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 100MHz
      capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cpufreq
      configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
    *-cache:0
         description: L1 cache
         physical id: 9
         slot: L1 Cache
         size: 32KiB
         capacity: 32KiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
    *-cache:1
         description: L2 cache
         physical id: a
         slot: L2 Cache
         size: 256KiB
         capacity: 256KiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
    *-cache:2
         description: L3 cache
         physical id: b
         slot: L3 Cache
         size: 3MiB
         capacity: 3MiB
         capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
 *-cache
      description: L1 cache
      physical id: 8
      slot: L1 Cache
      size: 32KiB
      capacity: 32KiB
      capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
 *-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 23
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 6GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: M471B5674QH0-YK0
         vendor: Samsung
         physical id: 0
         serial: 98D205AC
         slot: JDIMM1
         size: 2GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: NT4GC64C88B1NS-DI
         vendor: Nanya Technology
         physical id: 1
         serial: F85A1057
         slot: JDIMM2
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 09
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
    *-display
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:61 memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
    *-multimedia:0 UNCLAIMED
         description: Audio device
         product: Intel Corporation
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
         version: 09
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:b0710000-b0713fff
    *-usb:0
         description: USB controller
         product: Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 14
         bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
         resources: irq:58 memory:b0700000-b070ffff
    *-communication UNCLAIMED
         description: Communication controller
         product: Lynx Point-LP HECI #0
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 16
         bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:b0718000-b071801f
    *-multimedia:1 UNCLAIMED
         description: Audio device
         product: Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1b
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:b0714000-b0717fff
    *-pci:0
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
         version: e4
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:56 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:b0600000-b06fffff ioport:b0400000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            logical name: eth0
            version: 07
            serial: ec:f4:bb:87:45:0c
            size: 10Mbit/s
            capacity: 100Mbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
            resources: irq:60 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0600000-b0600fff memory:b0400000-b0403fff
    *-pci:1
         description: PCI bridge
         product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1c.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
         version: e4
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=pcieport
         resources: irq:57 memory:b0500000-b05fffff ioport:9fb00000(size=1048576)
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
            vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 01
            serial: 64:5a:04:ca:09:df
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.8.0-39-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
            resources: irq:19 memory:b0500000-b057ffff memory:9fb00000-9fb0ffff
    *-usb:1
         description: USB controller
         product: Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1d
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
         version: 04
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
         resources: irq:23 memory:b071c000-b071c3ff
    *-isa
         description: ISA bridge
         product: Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
         version: 04
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
         resources: irq:0
    *-storage
         description: SATA controller
         product: Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
         version: 04
         width: 32 bits
         clock: 66MHz
         capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
         resources: irq:59 ioport:4088(size=8) ioport:4094(size=4) ioport:4080(size=8) ioport:4090(size=4) ioport:4060(size=32) memory:b071b000-b071b7ff
    *-serial UNCLAIMED
         description: SMBus
         product: Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 1f.3
         bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
         version: 04
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:b0719000-b07190ff ioport:4040(size=32)
 *-scsi:0
      physical id: 1
      logical name: scsi0
      capabilities: emulated
    *-disk
         description: ATA Disk
         product: Hitachi HTS54757
         vendor: Hitachi
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sda
         version: JE4O
         serial: J2140054KYR1XB
         size: 698GiB (750GB)
         capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
         configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=0f7b0e6a-9fa4-449d-8fb3-524c80e127f4
       *-volume:0
            description: Windows FAT volume
            vendor: MSDOS5.0
            physical id: 1
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
            logical name: /dev/sda1
            logical name: /boot/efi
            version: FAT32
            serial: 0e9a-917c
            size: 495MiB
            capacity: 499MiB
            capabilities: boot fat initialized
            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI system partition state=mounted
       *-volume:1
            description: Windows FAT volume
            vendor: MSDOS5.0
            physical id: 2
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
            logical name: /dev/sda2
            version: FAT32
            serial: 600d-e074
            size: 15MiB
            capacity: 39MiB
            capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount fat initialized
            configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=Basic data partition
       *-volume:2
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 3
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
            logical name: /dev/sda3
            version: 3.1
            serial: 7214-8f07
            size: 98MiB
            capacity: 127MiB
            capabilities: nofs ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-04-26 20:59:47 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Microsoft reserved partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
       *-volume:3
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 4
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
            logical name: /dev/sda4
            version: 3.1
            serial: e012-cf26
            size: 460MiB
            capacity: 489MiB
            capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-02-07 18:33:16 filesystem=ntfs label=WINRETOOLS name=Basic data partition state=clean
       *-volume:4
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 5
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
            logical name: /dev/sda5
            version: 3.1
            serial: 8e282093-121f-2e48-901e-b0cc0d3175aa
            size: 201GiB
            capacity: 201GiB
            capabilities: ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-02-07 18:33:27 filesystem=ntfs label=OS name=Basic data partition state=clean
       *-volume:5
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 6
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,6
            logical name: /dev/sda6
            version: 3.1
            serial: 88bb-16a8
            size: 433MiB
            capacity: 449MiB
            capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-04-27 21:10:23 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
       *-volume:6
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 7
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,7
            logical name: /dev/sda7
            logical name: /media/sda7
            version: 3.1
            serial: 3a09b668-4147-4c4a-8f39-e329be48fcbf
            size: 341GiB
            capacity: 341GiB
            capabilities: ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-04-26 00:17:41 filesystem=ntfs label=Media modified_by_chkdsk=true mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=mounted upgrade_on_mount=true
       *-volume:7
            description: Windows NTFS volume
            physical id: 8
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,8
            logical name: /dev/sda8
            version: 3.1
            serial: 70f2-defe
            size: 12GiB
            capacity: 12GiB
            capabilities: precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
            configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-02-07 21:44:42 filesystem=ntfs label=PBR Image modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Microsoft recovery partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
       *-volume:8
            description: EXT4 volume
            vendor: Linux
            physical id: 9
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,9
            logical name: /dev/sda9
            logical name: /
            version: 1.0
            serial: a6c40c87-72a3-4600-a9f5-4e2164d727ad
            size: 135GiB
            capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
            configuration: created=2014-04-28 17:36:17 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2014-05-21 20:44:45 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2014-05-21 20:55:17 state=mounted
       *-volume:9
            description: Linux swap volume
            physical id: a
            bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,10
            logical name: /dev/sda10
            version: 1
            serial: 3cf35bdb-523c-4c09-8f2d-bed23767416c
            size: 6023MiB
            capacity: 6024MiB
            capabilities: nofs swap initialized
            configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
 *-scsi:1
      physical id: 2
      logical name: scsi1
      capabilities: emulated
    *-cdrom
         description: DVD-RAM writer
         product: DVD+-RW GU90N
         vendor: HL-DT-ST
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/cdrom
         logical name: /dev/cdrw
         logical name: /dev/dvd
         logical name: /dev/dvdrw
         logical name: /dev/sr0
         version: A100
         capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
         configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
       *-medium
            physical id: 0
            logical name: /dev/cdrom
 *-scsi:2
      physical id: 3
      bus info: usb@1:1.7
      logical name: scsi3
      capabilities: emulated scsi-host
      configuration: driver=rts5139
    *-disk
         description: SCSI Disk
         product: xD/SD/M.S.
         vendor: Generic-
         physical id: 0.0.0
         bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
         logical name: /dev/sdb
         version: 1.00
         serial: 3
         capabilities: removable
       *-medium
            physical id: 0
            logical name: /dev/sdb
*-battery
   description: Lithium-Ion Battery
   product: DELL 4WY7C416
   vendor: SANYO
   physical id: 1
   slot: Sys. Battery Bay
   capacity: 28000mWh
   configuration: voltage=14.8V
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) very useful and it helped me recover my sound. Don't forget to run sudo update-grub before each reboot.